# iMesh search uninstall

Tags: google-chrome

I really like Google Chrome but every time I go to Google  the imesh search engine come up I have gone to install/uninstall no avail. I have uninstalled google and re-installed nothing is named imesh

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Chrome issue per se but the imesh software which is inserting itself into your Chrome installation (this is usually considered an example of malware). You can edit your search engine preferences by going to the Chrome menu in the upper right and selecting Settings. In the "Search" section you can select "Manage search engines..."

From there you can remove items and set other providers as the default.

[image]